# Nginx doesnt pass request_query CakePhP

Tags: php, .htaccess, cakephp, nginx

I am trying to setup my `Cakephp` project on my Nginx server.

Now everything works fine however there is a problem.

When ever i try to pass paramters such as `mydomain.com/cake/users/view?searchvalue=test`

it doesnt work. because no query values is sent (i.e they are deleted, empty or gone).

Now i don't know if its my `Cake` htaccess thats interfering or if it is my server

(hence why i am posting this on `Stackoverflow` and not `ServerFault`, please note that if you think this should be on servers fault instead i will delete it and go there).

Here is my Nginx file:

```
    server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  my-domain.com;
    return 301 http://www.my-domain.com$request_uri;
}

server{
    listen      80 default;
    server_name     www.my-domain.com;


        location ~ [^/]\.php(/|$) {
                fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+?\.php)(/.*)$;
                if (!-f $document_root$fastcgi_script_name) {
                        return 404;
                }

                fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
                fastcgi_index index.php;
                include        /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
        #include fastcgi_params;
        }


    location ~ ^/cake/(.+)$ {
        index  index.php;

    set $val $1;

        try_files $uri $uri/ /cake/app/webroot/$val /cake/app/webroot/index.php/$val;

    }
```

Please tell me if you need more information!

Here is some additional information this is what it prints out when trying to go to my-domain.com/admin/test/servertest?laura this is when i echo the server variables:

```
   array (
  'USER' => 'apache',
  'HOME' => '/var/www',
  'FCGI_ROLE' => 'RESPONDER',
  'QUERY_STRING' => ' ', <---- **this is the problem**
  'REQUEST_METHOD' => 'GET',
  'CONTENT_TYPE' => '',
  'CONTENT_LENGTH' => '',
  'SCRIPT_FILENAME' => '/usr/share/nginx/html/cake/app/webroot/index.php',
  'SCRIPT_NAME' => '/cake/app/webroot/index.php',
  'PATH_INFO' => '',
  'REQUEST_URI' => '/cake/admin/employees/servertest?laura',
  'DOCUMENT_URI' => '/cake/app/webroot/index.php',
  'DOCUMENT_ROOT' => '/usr/share/nginx/html',
  'SERVER_PROTOCOL' => 'HTTP/1.1',
  'GATEWAY_INTERFACE' => 'CGI/1.1',
  'SERVER_SOFTWARE' => 'nginx/1.0.15',
  'REMOTE_ADDR' => '**.**.***.***',
  'REMOTE_PORT' => '53811',
  'SERVER_ADDR' => '***.**.***.***',
  'SERVER_PORT' => '80',
  'SERVER_NAME' => 'www.my-domain.com',
  'REDIRECT_STATUS' => '200',
  'HTTP_HOST' => 'www.my-domain.com',
  'HTTP_USER_AGENT' => 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:24.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/24.0',
  'HTTP_ACCEPT' => 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8',
  'HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE' => 'en-US,en;q=0.5',
  'HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING' => 'gzip, deflate',
  'HTTP_COOKIE' => 'bloglic_data[credentials]=Q2FrZQ%3D%3D.XG7at918B4h8lCRNBCdwg0Avi3ZNLdAn28Dl3vfOxaQkJAoJFYxZ0s1a%2Fp3RLB2%2B5krPCIBKFboN4y1X4lY4%2FFautJJ7ce6VyN%2BOgLFbR4KUzn5g7QGDlZS2YqB%2FbZ%2FghYfKzcZvzkYYkvtj9dQkozRMaUPWY8%2F910tf7fnpk8EFAQ%3D%3D; CAKEPHP=7c411r3pc7vhjk3vjqjoplmtk3',
  'HTTP_CONNECTION' => 'keep-alive',
  'PHP_SELF' => '/cake/app/webroot/index.php',
  'REQUEST_TIME_FLOAT' => 1382965704.0475,
  'REQUEST_TIME' => 1382965704,
)
```

Comment: This question is better suited to serverfault - [there are existing questions+answers covering this](http://serverfault.com/questions/231578/nginx-php-fpm-where-are-my-get-params/362924#362924)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Obligatory `if is evil`: http://wiki.nginx.org/IfIsEvil

Credits to pasela for this: https://gist.github.com/pasela/3052624

```
#
# nginx configuration example for CakePHP 2.x
#
server {
  listen       80;
  server_name  cakephp2.example;
  root         /var/www/cakephp2/app/webroot;

  access_log  /var/log/nginx/cakephp2.access.log;
  error_log  /var/log/nginx/cakephp2.error.log;

  location / {
      index  index.php;
      try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
  }

  location ~ \.php$ {
      include        fastcgi_params;
      fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
      fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
  }

  location ~ \.php/ {
      include        fastcgi_params;
      fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.*)$;
      fastcgi_param  PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
      fastcgi_param  PATH_TRANSLATED  $document_root$fastcgi_path_info;
      fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
      fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
  }

  location = /favicon.ico {
      log_not_found off;
      access_log off;
  }

  location = /robots.txt {
      log_not_found off;
      access_log off;
  }

  #error_page  404              /404.html;
  #location = /404.html {
  #    root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
  #}  

  # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
  #
  error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
  location = /50x.html {
      root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
  }

  # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
  # concurs with nginx's one
  #
  location ~ /(\.ht|\.user.ini|\.git|\.hg|\.bzr|\.svn) {
      deny  all;
  }
```

}

It's what I came across after having mod_rewrite problems when I first installed Cake. You can change things around, for example I use `unix socket` with `fastcgi_pass` instead of `TCP/IP socket`.

Answer (score 1):

try changing this in your `try_files`

```
/cake/app/webroot/index.php/$val;
```

to this

```
/cake/app/webroot/index.php/$val$is_args$query_string;
```